# Codable conformance at @Published array of a codable-conformed Struct

Tags: swift, struct, swiftui, codable, urlsession

I am tinkering around with URLSession and was essentially building a super simple app to load a JSON file into ContentView sort of like a friends list from Facebook and wanted some clarity on not any errors I'm having, but rather, the internal workings of Swift's `Codable` protocol. Here are some code and explanations:

```
struct User: Identifiable, Codable {
    struct Friend : Identifiable, Codable {
        var name : String
        var id : String
    }

    var id : String
    var isActive: Bool
    var name : String
    var age: Int
    var company : String
    var address : String
    var about : String
    var registered : String
    
    var friends : [Friend]
    
    var checkIsActive: String {
        return self.isActive ? "" :""
    }
    
}
```

So to summarize above, I have a `User` struct which contains a bunch of properties that conform to `Codable`.

```
class UsersArrayClass: ObservableObject {
    @Published var userArray = [User]() 
}
```

However, I have another class, `UsersArrayClass` which creates a `@Published var userArray` of `User` struct objects. This class conforms to the `@ObservableObject` protocol, but of course, when I try to make it conform to `Codable`, it does not like that likely because of the `@Published` property wrapper being applied on the array itself... This is what is essentially confusing me though if the User struct has `Codable` conformance, why doesn't `userArray` which contains `User` objects automatically conform to `Codable` as well?

I was thinking that maybe loading all of this up into a Core Data model would solve my problems, but I still can't move on unless I understand what I'm missing out on here, so thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: `@Published` is what doesn't conform to `Codable`. So, the compiler cannot auto-synthesize the `Codable` conformance. This unfortunately means that you'd need to do so manually, i.e. by implementing with `init(from:)` and `encode(to:)`. See how to do this [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/adding-codable-conformance-for-published-properties).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
/*
 Cannot automatically synthesize 'Encodable' because 'Published<[User]>'
 does not conform to 'Encodable' @Published var userArray = [User]()
 */

// Published declaration
@propertyWrapper struct Published<Value> { ... }
```

**Published don't conform to Codable or any common protocol in Foundation currently**

Trying to make `Published` conform to `Codeable` resulting error below:

```
/*
 Implementation of 'Decodable' cannot be
 automatically synthesized in an extension in a different file to the type
 */
extension Published: Codable where Value: Codable {}
```

Comment: But if User Conforms to Codable, how come Published<User> cannot? Is it simply the nature of the @Published property wrapper that it does not work that?

Comment: I have modified my answer to explained how `Published<User>` can not conform to `Codable`. Because `Published` doesn't conform to any protocol at this time.
You can't event extend `Published` to adapt `Codable`.

Answer (score 1):

It is hacky, but we can via extension add `Codable` conformance to `Published` despite lacking access to `Published` internals.

```
extension Published: Codable where Value: Codable {
    public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        guard
            let storageValue =
                Mirror(reflecting: self).descendant("storage")
                .map(Mirror.init)?.children.first?.value,
            let value =
                storageValue as? Value
                ??
                (storageValue as? Publisher).map(Mirror.init)?
                .descendant("subject", "currentValue")
                as? Value
        else { fatalError("Failed to encode") }
        
        try value.encode(to: encoder)
    }
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        self.init(initialValue: try .init(from: decoder))
    }
}
```

Quick check:

```
class User: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var name = "Paul"
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var user = User()
    var body: some View {
        let data = try? JSONEncoder().encode(user)
        let dataFromStr = """
                {
                    "name": "Smith"
                }
                """
            .data(using: .utf8)
        let decoded = try! JSONDecoder().decode(User.self, from: dataFromStr!)
        return
            VStack{
                Text(verbatim: String(data: data!, encoding: .utf8) ?? "encoding failed")
                Text(decoded.name)
            }
    }
}
```